# How to find $a$ that solves the following equation for $x > 0$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Can someone please help me figure out how to solve this?
$$
6 + \int\limits_a^{x^2}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt = 2\sqrt{x}.
$$

Comment: Without even knowing what $\;f\;$ is?! And what's your own work...?

Comment: The left hand clearly depends on the function $f$.

Comment: By the way, type **6+\int\limits_a^{x^2}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\cdot dt=2\sqrt x** to generate $$6+\int\limits_a^{x^2}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\cdot dt=2\sqrt x$$

Comment: actually, they didn't give f. That's what's been bugging me about this problem.

Comment: @user477343 you can just use \int_{a}^{x^2} for the limits

Comment: @RhysHughes no it formats differently. **\int_{a}^{x^2}** generates $$\int_{a}^{x^2}$$ and note that this is different from **\int\limits_{a}^{x^2}** which is $$\int\limits_{a}^{x^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $x^2=a$, then the integral is zero.  Therefore, if $x=\sqrt{a}$, then

$$
6=2\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Note: If you wanted to find $f$, you can take the derivative of both sides to get

$$
\frac{f(x^2)}{x^4}(2x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.
$$
Then, solve for $f(x^2)$ and substitute $y=x^2$.  This will give you a formula for $f$.

Comment: So, the only solution is a = 81?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the solution.